# Проблема повторной установки MySQL на Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

После полного удаления MySQL при попытке его установки происходит следующая ошибка
Способ описанный [здесь](https://qna.habr.com/q/461943) не помог

```
Настраивается пакет mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.29-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) …
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-5.7.postinst: строка 143: /usr/share/mysql-common/configure-symlinks: Нет такого файла или каталога
dpkg: ошибка при обработке пакета mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 подпроцесс установлен сценарий post-installation возвратил код ошибки 1
Настраивается пакет mysql-client (5.7.29-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) …
dpkg: зависимости пакетов не позволяют настроить пакет mysql-server:
 mysql-server зависит от mysql-server-5.7, однако:
  Пакет mysql-server-5.7 пока не настроен.

dpkg: ошибка при обработке пакета mysql-server (--configure):
 проблемы зависимостей — оставляем не настроенным
Отчёт apport не записан, так как сообщение об ошибке указывает на повторную ошибку от предыдущего отказа.
                         Обрабатываются триггеры для libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu11) …
Обрабатываются триггеры для systemd (229-4ubuntu21.27) …
Обрабатываются триггеры для ureadahead (0.100.0-19.1) …
При обработке следующих пакетов произошли ошибки:
 mysql-server-5.7
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
Ошибка при выполнении запрошенной операции с пакетом. Попытка восстановить:
Настраивается пакет mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.29-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) …
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-5.7.postinst: строка 143: /usr/share/mysql-common/configure-symlinks: Нет такого файла или каталога
dpkg: ошибка при обработке пакета mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 подпроцесс установлен сценарий post-installation возвратил код ошибки 1
dpkg: зависимости пакетов не позволяют настроить пакет mysql-server:
 mysql-server зависит от mysql-server-5.7, однако:
  Пакет mysql-server-5.7 пока не настроен.

dpkg: ошибка при обработке пакета mysql-server (--configure):
 проблемы зависимостей — оставляем не настроенным
При обработке следующих пакетов произошли ошибки:
 mysql-server-5.7
 mysql-server
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение оказалось простым, просто установил [MariaDB](https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-mariadb-10-3-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts-xenial/) и все заработало

Answer (score 0):

не полностью удалили MySql sudo apt purge

Comment: Почему вы так решили?